# Issue with sending prn files to printer : Printing is extremely slow

Tags: windows, printing, command-prompt, zebra-printers, barcode-printing

I am generating prn files for printer via php and sending them to the printer for print using

```
COPY filename.prn /B \\ComputerName\NetworkPrinterName
```

FYI this command is being executed manually.

When I am doing this the printing is happening a lot slower then when its happen directly through through an application. I primarily concerned with this issue with a Zebra Label Printer.

What happens with the software is the when I give an option to print 20 copies of label its prints them in 5-10 seconds max

When I print it through a prn file with the above command. It literally takes 1 second per label.

By the way the prn files generated by me using php and the software are 100% percent similar. I am actually using a common template in php for all the barcode which took from one of the label prn file which I generated from the software itself and just changing product related values no change in design or structure.

I looked at the EPL documentation for the zebra printer i couldn't find out issue from it and probably because I didn't understand it quite well.

My PRN File Structure

```
I8,A,001


Q160,008
q863
rN
S2
D10
ZT
JF
OP
R279,0
f100
N
A3,4,0,1,1,1,N,"ADWANTA TRUNK COL 100"
A28,30,1,4,1,1,N,"D-Mart"
B35,21,0,1,2,6,46,B,"1000256381"
A35,99,0,2,2,2,N,"Rs117"
A182,98,0,2,1,1,N," MRP"
A182,114,0,2,1,1,N,"Rs130"
P20
```

THE NO NEXT TO P(LAST LINE) IS USED TO DETERMINE THE QUANTITY. N i change it dynamically through php based on my requirements

Comment: @JustinC can you give me the exact syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the final `P1` to `P20` - the number following `P` is copies-to-print

---

Since that didn't work, try changing the S2 to S3 and so on to S6. The max speed setting depends on printer model. Even so, S2 should give you 2" per second...

---

In the absence of a response to whether the "S" command change affected matters, I'll offer the source, [EPL Programming Guide](https://support.zebra.com/cpws/docs/eltron/epl2/EPL2_Prog.pdf) - which should be official and credible enough - page 144, or "EPL2 Programmer's Manual" (Zebra manual No 98009-001 Revision D) Page 2-56

Comment: I always change it based on my based on needs. I don't send P1 at all. Thanks anyways. If you can think of any other problem in it

Comment: Will try it and let you know.it that mentioned anywhere some documentation. please point me out to the source.

Comment: I tried generating a few different PRN files noticed that they didn't have the "OP" characters instead they had just "O" and so I made the change and now its printing the documents in good speed. Thanks a lot